# Google App Engine: Outputting 'values' from a SearchResult object on Jinja2 template.

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2, google-search-api

I would like to return the field `value`s of a SearchDocument's object. For example, I have generated a SearchResult object using:

```
class SearchResult(Handler):
    def get(self):
    index = search.Index("INDEX_NAME")
    results = index.search("Brian")
    self.render('search-result.html', results = results)
```

The results object looks something like this:

```
search.SearchResults(results=[
    search.ScoredDocument(
        doc_id=u'6122080743456768', 
        fields=[search.TextField(name=u'full_name', value=u"Brian Jones"), 
        language=u'en', 
        rank=106509239L), 
    search.ScoredDocument(
        doc_id=u'4714705859903488', 
        fields=[search.TextField(name=u'full_name', value=u"Brian Lara"), 
        language=u'en', 
        rank=106427057L)], 
    number_found=2L)
```

Inside **search-result.html**, how can I return the `value`s of the fields?

```
...
<body>
{{ field_values }} #return the field values "Brian Lara" and "Brian Jones"
<body>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start here:

```
{% for result in results %}
  {{ result.fields[0].value }}
{% endfor %}
```

(You have a '[' mismatch in your fields.  Fix that, then check the syntax)

Comment: Thanks for answering, @GAEfan. Is there no way to explicitly return the value for `full_name`, instead of using the nth fields[0]? The reason for this is because my documents are indexed at different periods and sometimes fields[0] returns a different field.

Comment: I would need to see the structure, but it sounds like you'd want to loop through the items and check:

Comment: for item in fields:     if item.name == "full_name":    value = item.value. (Sorry, cannot get proper formatting on this ipad, but you get the idea)

Comment: `if item.has_key("name") and item.name == "full_name":    value = ...`. I would probably build the list in Python, then send it to the template via jinja.